Selenium Chrome Webdriver not working on Google Colab
I tried to initialize selenium on google colab using :
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

print(chrome_options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

after installing selenium using
%%shell
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

# Install chromium and chromium-driver
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium chromium-driver

# Install selenium
pip install selenium

That was from the post here
I received the error
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x7aa3e3f26860>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-123981fb5389> in <cell line: 99>()
     97 print(chrome_options)
     98 
---> 99 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    100 
    101 def check_html_content(html_content, url):

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

How can I use selenium (python) on google colab? I'm not very familiar with the selenium options etc, so I'm not sure how to use it. If someone could please tell me how to use selenium python on google colab, I would be very grateful.

you have to read documentation for Chrome(...) because Selenium changed many things and you use very old method. Newer version doesn't need 'chromedriver' but Service(). And it can treats positional parameter 'chromedriver' as options="chromedriver", and  this way you may have two options=... in your code - and it shows error got multiple values for argument 'options'.  But the newest version doesn't need even Service() because it can automatically download driver. So you may need only Chrome(options=chrome_options)

Selenium changed code in newer versions and it seems you use very old code.
It treats positional parameter "chromedriver" as named parameter options="chromedriver" and this gives two options=... in your code, and this generates error got multiple values for argument 'options'
Newer versions need:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver"), 
    options=chrome_options
)

or you can use special module to automatically download driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), 
    options=chrome_options
)

But the newest version can automatically download driver so you can even do
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


Selenium-Python doc: Chrome Driver, Chrome Service
Selenium doc: Service
